# Ripple drawable in xml not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm stuck with a problem: I have an xml drawable that I wanna use as background for a radiobutton, but the ripple effect isn't working. Can anyone help me with that?

My xml for the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#8bc34a" >
<item>
   <selector>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/tb_checked" android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent"></item>
</selector>
</item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: Read the RippleDrawable documentation. The ripple is masked against the content. Your content is transparent when unchecked.

Comment: @alanv So how do I fix it? Do I add `android:id="@android:id/mask` in my item tag?

Comment: It depends on what effect you're trying to achieve. What you have right now specifies no background when not checked and a ripple drawn atop  @drawable/tb_checked when checked.

Comment: @alanv I want tb_checked to be my background, when the radiobutton is checked, but I also want a ripple effect, when pressed or selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to show an unbounded ripple above or below additional content, use a `<layer-list>` container to stack them and don't put any content inside the `<ripple>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="#8bc34a" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/tb_checked"
                  android:state_checked="true" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works fine for Buttons now, but for RadioButtons there's still no ripple. Do you know how to fix that, too?

Comment: Are you using setBackground() on the RadioButton or setButtonDrawable()? The latter doesn't support projected (unbounded) ripples.

Comment: I'm doing it in XML with the android:background attribute

Comment: May be a framework bug. Could you file an issue on the AOSP issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry/ with sample code to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: I have the same issue. It works for button but not radioButton (

Comment: This works perfectly if you just want to have a transparent background. In that case the `<item><selector><item(s)>` can be replaced by a single transparent drawable `<icon>`-tag. --- oh, but the performance of the ripple suffers tremendously

Comment: This works fine for any drawable on radio button. Tested on Lollipop and Marshmallow. (If this was a problem, may be it has to do with build tools and probably they fixed it there)

Answer (score 1):

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="Choice 1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_choice_white"
    android:button="@null"/>
```

In the v1-drawable add the background drawable with ripple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:state_checked="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/button_choice_background"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

In RadioButton xml declaration add this attribute 
 **android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"**
I am pretty sure this will work.

Comment: Thats not really what I wanted. I want a customized background with backwards compatibility. But thank you for your answer!